# OOM error when running Keras(Tensorflow backend) on GPU. The same script runs to completion on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am getting the following error when running a keras script on GPU:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1032192,500] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[Node: training/Adam/mul_63 = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Adam/beta_2/read, training/Adam/Variable_28/read)]]
```

This script runs fine on CPU, albeit very slowly.

I have tried reducing batch size all the way down to 1, and the problem still occurs. I tried re-scaling the images as well.

Is there another way to reduce the memory being used? Has anyone run into this?

Comment: [This is relevant](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1817)

Comment: Few things you can try, 1. if it's possible try reducing the complexity of your model (e.g. number of layers in your CNN) 2. Have operations that produce large tensors inside the clause `with tf.device('/cpu:0')` specificially 3. If it doesn't cost performance, try using a simpler optimizer like SGD then you will have less tensors being produced.